# How can I set custom key assignments for autostart?

Tags: x11, kde, keyboard, manjaro

I used the `xkbcomp $DISPLAY ~/.Xkbmap` command to export the current settings.
After that I changed some key assignments, created a file `~/.xprofile` and added the line `xkbcomp $HOME/.Xkbmap $DISPLAY` to it

If I execute this file manually - everything works correctly, but only once, the next presses are as if no customization was applied.
Also if I reboot or restart the session, these settings are not applied.
I experimented with autorun options, pausing and testing, and then came to the conclusion that KDE reassigns this setting after all initialization scripts.
I tried pausing for 10 seconds and testing the buttons - it doesn't work for a while, then the initialization script runs and everything works correctly, after that it resets.

I can not so slow down the initialization of the system, and the method with a pause looks, to put it mildly, ugly.

My task is to change the default values of NumPad - I don't use it and want to use these buttons instead of shortcuts.
I originally used .Xmodmap, but there's some bug in there that when I clicked on a changed button, it started generating a large number of clicks of that button, which caused the whole system to hang

I'm using Manjaro

Kernel: 6.6.0-1-MANJARO (64-bit)

KDE Plasma: 5.27.9